# Codename One Issue publishing ios 64 bit app on store

Tags: ios, codenameone, publishing

Deploying an app to ios store I get the following error: ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64 bit support...".

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

In attachment some screenshots.

Thanks
[publishing app with application loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I06wy.png)
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kInj3.png)

Update:

I've done as Shai Almog said. This is the output:

```
Macintosh:MyApplication.appmtk$ file MyApplication
MyApplication: Mach-O universalbinary with 2 architectures
MyApplication (for architecture armv7): Mach-O executablearm
MyApplication (for architecturecputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0)):  Mach-O 64-bit executable
Macintosh:MyApplication.appmtk$
```

Comment: Did you google the error? Did you use what it recommends in the error?

Comment: Do you use any 3rd party libraries? If so one of them might include a 32 bit error that could trigger that error.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried a build and uploaded it. You can verify a binary has 64 bit support by unzipping the ipa and doing something similar to:

```
file IPAZipDir/Payload/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
```

The output should look like this:

> Payload/MyApplication.app/MyApplication: Mach-O universal binary with
>   2 architectures Payload/MyApplication.app/MyApplication (for
>   architecture armv7):  Mach-O executable arm
>   Payload/MyApplication.app/MyApplication (for architecture
>   arm64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable

Comment: In first post you can see my output

Comment: Do you have an old version of Mac OS or Application Loader? It looks from the output that your Mac doesn't recognize arm64 so it's possible this is failing the application loader.

Comment: Shai Almog was right. I had to make an overall update. Thanks.